# How to Parse an orderedDict?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

```
OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Campaign__c'), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Campaign__c/a0B9000000I6CDUEA3')])), (u'clicks__c', 0.0)])
```

I have an ordered dict like above how do I get the value of `clicks__c`?

Comment: `object["clicks__c"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is still a dictionary, just use the key:

```
your_ordered_dict['clicks__c']
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Campaign__c'), (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Campaign__c/a0B9000000I6CDUEA3')])), (u'clicks__c', 0.0)])
>>> od.keys()
[u'attributes', u'clicks__c']
>>> od['clicks__c']
0.0
```

If you parsed this from a JSON object, in the vast majority of cases *order won't matter*. It certainly doesn't with your values here. You could just have parsed it to regular dictionaries and not lost functionality.